# How to access cell in heightForRowAtIndexPath in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was searching for how can i make cell height dynamic.Luckily i have found [Uitable dynamic height](https://github.com/PaulSolt/AutoLayoutForUITableViewCell) github project which makes cell height dynamic according to content.

In the code cell is accessed in **heightForRowAtIndexPath** but i am confuesed here in the code that same code of **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is used in **heightForRowAtIndexPath**.Do i need to repeat the code what if the code is lengthy?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

    cell.fontNameLabel.text = _fontArray[indexPath.row];

    int quoteIndex = indexPath.row % [_quoteArray count];
    cell.quoteLabel.text = _quoteArray[quoteIndex];
    NSString *fontName = _fontArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.quoteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:17];
    return cell;

}

// NOTE: in iOS 8 you can use the automatic height calculations from AutoLayout,
//  and you can avoid writing this height method. Just comment it out, and uncomment
//  the line in viewDidLoad for
//  _tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Calculate a height based on a cell
    if(!self.customCell) {
        self.customCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    self.customCell.fontNameLabel.text = _fontArray[indexPath.row];

    int quoteIndex = indexPath.row % [_quoteArray count];
    self.customCell.quoteLabel.text = _quoteArray[quoteIndex];
    NSString *fontName = _fontArray[indexPath.row];
    self.customCell.quoteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:17];


    // Layout the cell

    [self.customCell layoutIfNeeded];

    // Get the height for the cell

    CGFloat height = [self.customCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    // Padding of 1 point (cell separator)
    CGFloat separatorHeight = 1;

    return height + separatorHeight;
}
```

Comment: do you support iOS 7 ? from iOS 8 this is done automatically

Comment: Interesting.  The code you found cheats by creating a cell that won't be added to the table view and configuring it the same way it would if it were being inserted.  This may work for simple cells, but if you are including images or any other CPU-intensive task in your cell configuration, this is beyond horrible.

Comment: As to your question about repeating code, are you not aware of subroutines/functions/methods/procedures and how to use them to factor out common code?